# Expressions vs Lambdas

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I know what a Lambda Expression is.

But I am not sure if that is the same thing as an `Expression`.  There seems to be more to know here than I know.

I am looking at [wrapping IQueryable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/03/01/tip-55-how-to-extend-an-iqueryable-by-wrapping-it.aspx) and that uses Expressions a lot.  So, for example, is there more to the 'Expression' parameter here than can be thought of in a Lambda?

```
public InterceptedQuery(InterceptingProvider provider, Expression expression) 
{ 
    this._provider = provider; 
    this._expression = expression; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A *lambda expression* is a compiler feature that is compiled, depending on context, into one of two things:

- A (hidden) function and a delegate to it
- An `Expression`

Once the application has been compiled, the concept of a lambda expression doesn't exist, as it's been turned into one of the above two options.

I'm not sure what you mean by

> is there more to the 'Expression' parameter here than can be thought of in a Lambda

An expression encapsulates and expressed application logic in an inspectable form (in other words, it lets you see what the developer wrote in terms of properties and functions invoked, constants included, comparisons, etc.). This is how query providers (for the most part, object-relational mappers like the Entity Framework) take code and turn it into SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas are generally compiled code, where Expression represents "abstract syntax trees" (AST), ie. a data structure that represents code, and can be compiled to code. IQueryable generally operates on Expression because it's supposed to compile the AST to code that runs in different environments, like an SQL server, instead of just the host machine. There are IQueryableProviders that compile to SQL (Linq2Sql), to JavaScript, to OpenGL shaders (Bling), and more.

The C# compiler can sometimes turn a lambda into an expression, if the method parameter expects an expression of the right type:

```
void Foo(Expression<Func<int>>) { ... }
...
Foo(() => 3);
```

Comment: "Lambdas are generally compiled code" This is incorrect, while lambdas can certainly be used to create compiled code (they become delegates to hidden, compiler-generated functions), they are also used to create `Expression` objects; whichever one is created is determined by the context. I mot going to downvote, since your information on AST's is certainly correct, but the first sentence implies that there is a difference between Lambdas and Expressions.

Comment: Emphasis on the *generally*. The full expressive power of lambdas are only available to delegates at the moment, because "statement lambdas" can't compile to expressions. Expression is an impoverished subset of lambdas. I'd also estimate that the majority of lambda use is System.Linq, which use delegates, but perhaps I'm biased on that estimate.

Comment: I'd disagree there; I think that the majority of LINQ statements come as part of LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework queries (other ORM's obviously support Expression syntax, too, but I wouldn't think their usage is anywhere near as high as EF or L2S). I think that the fact that the overwhelming majority of "LINQ" questions on StackOverflow reference one of those two frameworks (EF is starting to take over as the majority share, but L2S is no slouch).